# Change tempo of spotify track Swift

Tags: swift, spotify

Hi I've integrated spotify in my app. I just want to change the tempo (Beat Per Minute) of the track. Can anyboady tell me how this can be achieved?

I want to increase or decrease the tempo of current running song. I have the tempo of the song. Currently i'm playing song with their native player.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269879/how-to-change-bpm-value-of-spotify-song-swift), my question in the comments section still stands

Answer (score 0):

You should really provide some code. Not sure what player (Spotify's native player?) you're using or what you've tried.

Anyway, (for example) if you have the audio sample loaded via their API as an URL within `AVAudioPlayer`

```
player.enableRate = true
player.rate = 2.0
```